# DVI vs VGA on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, dvi, vga

I have a 3 monitor setup (each monitor is exactly the same). Two videocards, each with one splitter (one DVI and one VGA). I have two monitors hooked up using DVI and the third is connected through the VGA connection. I am running Windows 7.

If I resize a window from one DVI monitor to the other, it's not a problem. It does so very smoothly. If I resize a window on the VGA monitor it is extremely choppy.

Why? It's not choppy on other machines with only VGA connections. Has anyone else noticed this?

Comment: What do you mean by "resize a window from one DVI monitor to the other"? Modern graphics cards should be capable of supporting two displays at reasonable resolutions, so I guess the problem is with the connection or digital-to-analog chip. Maybe when you moved the windows across, the sudden change in the electrical signal causes some interference that is not properly handled. Similar effect is quite common for composite signals, but not so much for VGA though.

Comment: I have a window on monitor 1 and it resizes smoothly. Same with monitor 2. But on monitor 3 it is very choppy.